# Multiple row SQL where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

This is probably a simple SQL statement but right now I have a "brain freeze".

I have this table

```
variant_id | filter_id
1585593211       4
1585593211       48
1585593212       4
1585593212       49
```

I need to get variant_id that have filters_id: 4 and 48. In this case I expect to get 1585593211

Comment: please include your attempt as well.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IN` to get all rows with `filter_id` `4` or `48`. Then `GROUP BY variant_id` and check, that the count of distinct `filter_id`s is equal to 2 in a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT variant_id
       FROM elbat
       WHERE filter_id IN (4, 48)
       GROUP BY variant_id
       HAVING count(DISTINCT filter_id) = 2;
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works properly because it uses `DISTINCT`.  Might be `>=2` depending on whether the actual problem is "must have only 4 & 48" or "must have both 4 & 48"

Answer (score 2):

This is a "sets-within-sets" query

You can try to get `count` base on the condition, then find the `variant_id` count equal `2`

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   variant_id INT,
   filter_id INT
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES (1585593211,4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1585593211,48);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1585593212,4);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1585593212,49);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT variant_id
FROM T t1
where filter_id in (4,48)
group by variant_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

| variant_id |
| ---------- |
| 1585593211 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jCxC22TeRKSgpCeUqtxFdN/0)

or

```
select variant_id
from T
group by variant_id
having sum(filter_id = 4) > 0 and 
       sum(filter_id = 48) > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT variant_id
FROM TABLENAME where filter_id in (4,48) group by variant_id having count(distinct filter_id)>1;
```

group by ,where filter_id would filter all the data which has 4 and 48
for a specific variant ID.
but the actual requirements would be met when we add
 `having count(distinct filter_id)>1;`
this would make sure **both** **4 and 48** would be there in the filter_id.

Comment: You need `count(distinct *)` otherwise multiple 4s or  48s will result in a row.

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please explain your code, though is self explanatory.

Comment: explained.. as per your suggestions